# The stream or file "/vagrant/storage/logs/laravel-****-**-**.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: laravel, composer-php, vagrantfile, vagrant-windows

i'm desperately trying to setup a Vagrant machine on my Windows 10 laptop to start working with Laravel 5.8, i know there are 100 questions like these around the web and stackoverflow but none of them seem to solve my problem.

I keep getting the execption 
`The stream or file "/vagrant/storage/logs/laravel-****-**-**.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied` when i enter my website url.

**It does not seem like a permission issue, even when i chmod the directory to 777 it still wont work.**

Im used to my macbook where it almost works out of the box. However i cant get it to work on my Windows machine, which is no surprise to me.
[image: Permissions of the folders]

The vagrant file synced folder

`config.vm.synced_folder "./", "/vagrant", type: "smb", owner: "vagrant", group: "www-data"`

The box i am using

`config.vm.box = "ubuntu/bionic64"`

`config.vm.box_url = "https://app.vagrantup.com/ubuntu/boxes/bionic64/versions/20181211.0.0/providers/virtualbox.box"`

Hopefully someone can help me i have no clue why this happens as everything seems fine.

Comment: At what point do you get that error? During vagrant up? Also, take a look at Homestead - purpose-built VM for Laravel - https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/homestead

Comment: @JDev518 when i visit the url i configured to load the application. I am familiar with Homestead but on my mac it was easier to user my own vm, maybe if this doesn't work out i will try out homestead again.

Comment: If you are using linux, try to use this command `sudo chmod -R 777 /vagrant/storage/logs`

Comment: @EduardoJunior already tried that and dit not work either, which is pretty weird

Comment: You're mounting your folder via SMB? You'll have to make sure your _windows_ folder permissions are set to allow read/write for everyone.

Comment: @DarrylE.Clarke yes, NFS does not work so i tried out SMB and it 'worked' to the point where i got stuck on the permissions. Will try it out, thanks.

Comment: @DarrylE.Clarke i setup a permission on Everyone and allowed everything thats possible in the GUI, but it still wont work..

Answer (score 5):

```
sudo vi /etc/php/7.2/fpm/pool.d/www.conf
```

change:

```
user = www-data
group = www-data
```

to

```
user = vagrant
group = vagrant
```

Then:

```
sudo service php7.2-fpm restart
```